# Store http request to variable then have seperate http request pass to frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I’m planning some changes to how users interact with the data served on the front end of my web app.
This app streams news feeds from twitter. Currently the front end built with angular sends an http request that is passed to a route in my node backend. The backend uses the Twitter api to load the response. As my user base grows though the requests will be too expensive to maintain. Instead I want my backed to use a timer and make a Twitter api request, Store the data in a variable and then serve that data to the user on the front end. 
What would be the method for me to do that?

Backend:
1. Node http.request to Twitter API using timer
2. Seperate route that handles the incoming request from the angular front end.

Front end:
3. Http request from front end that sends the request to the route (2) in the backend.

I thought I could use promises but i’m now sure how chaining would work here.

Comment: I would suggest using a cache library in your node backend. If the value exists in the cache, send that back, otherwise go off to the Twitter API. You can use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache

Answer (score 0):

For your backend server I'd suggest to create an API cache with Redis to optimize the performance, due to less information about your code, I can help you with an example to create your own one by implementing it with your Angular and node due:

https://www.compose.com/articles/api-caching-with-redis-and-nodejs/

hope it help you!